# Finding the maximum sum of a column for any 3 rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask the following question

I have a table with many rows and the following columns

```
sender, recipient, value
```

For example

```
sender  recipient   value
smith   williams     500
smith   taylor       100
smith   vagelis      200
vagelis taylor       150
giorgos taylor       150
nikos   taylor       200
smith   Kostas       300
```

I would like to find the maximum sum of values for any 3 rows and for all specific senders.

In my example

```
smith   800
giorgos 150
vagelis 150
nikos   200
```

And finally to find all the senders that their maximum sum for any 3 rows is above 500.This is my finally goal.

In my example

```
smith 800
```

Thank you in advance

**Update**
I found the solution with the help of @Prdp post

```
select distinct a.sender,a.total_sum from(
 SELECT t1.sender,(t1.value+ t2.value + t3.value)
       as total_sum
    FROM    
    transfers2  t1, transfers2 t2, transfers2 t3
          where 
              t1.sender = t2.sender
           and t3.sender = t2.sender
             and t1.date!=t2.date 
             and t1.date!=t3.date
             and t2.date!=t3.date
             ) a
             where a.total_sum>500
```

Comment: Edit your question and post some sample data / desired results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach (Not efficient). Gordan's approach is much better than this

```
SELECT Distinct sender
FROM   (SELECT t1.sender,
               CASE cnt
                 WHEN 1 THEN t1.value
                 WHEN 2 THEN t1.value + t2.value
                 ELSE t1.value + t2.value + t3.value
               END total_sum
        FROM   (SELECT sender,value,Count(1) OVER(partition BY sender) AS cnt FROM yourtable) t1
               JOIN yourtable t2
                 ON t1.sender = t2.sender
               JOIN yourtable t3
                 ON t3.sender = t2.sender) a 
Where total_sum > 500
```

You can filter the sender by adding a `Where` clause

**Update :** Based on the edit, you just need simple `Group by` and `Having` clause

```
Select sender,sum(value)
From yourtable 
Group by sender
Having sum(value) > 500
```

Comment: Order by `total_sum` rather than the `row_number`.  Also, you need some sort of `id` to guarantee that the same row is not being used three times.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Used `Row_number` just incase OP wants to do the same for more than one `sender`. Updated to handle same row is not being used three/two times when count is less than three

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I get an error message and I cannot run the query
Invalid column name 'total_sum'.

Comment: @vagelis - check now. updated based on your requirement

Comment: You are very close!
I have edited my first post could you please check it?
Your query gives as a result 


sender total_sum

giorgos    150
nikos        200
smith        1500
vagelis      150

which is not the correct result.
Smith's value has to be 800

Comment: @Prdp I just saw the update.
You forgot that I want this only for 3 rows combinations, not for all the existences

Comment: @vagelis Sorry missed it.. Its 12 Am here may b I should get some sleep  will get back to you tomo morning

Comment: @Prdp ok thank you for your help!
I hope that someone helps with this because I need the answer for an exam tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

I am interpreting the question as your wanting the maximum sum for any three rows in the table.  If you choose three rows and want the maximum, just choose the rows with non-negative values.

The maximum sum would be the rows with the three largest values, if you want to maximize the sum:

```
select sum(value)
from (select top 3 t.*
      from t
      order by value desc
     ) t;
```

You might also want to add `where value >= 0` if most values are negative and "3" means "at most 3".

If you want the maximum for a particular sender, then add `where sender = @sender` to the subquery.

Comment: Thanks this is nice!
How can I do that if I want the same calculation for a specific recipient or sender?

Comment: Sory, I didn't say it well I have edited my first post
If you don't mind can you please check it one more time?

Answer (score 0):

This will give the sender name who has made three transaction > 500

```
SELECT sender 
FROM transfers t
GROUP BY sender
HAVING   (select sum(value) from (select top 3 transfers.* from transfers
          where sender = t.sender order by value desc) t1  ) >=500
```